# Adding an item to layout

Tags: qgis, layouts

I'm using QGIS 3.28.11 and when I create a layout in a raster file, I can add a N arrow and Legend but when I add a scale bar all it shows is a vertical dash line, can't see it in the layout. It shows that I've added it in the TOC on the right. I've added this in the past. I can't figure out why the scale bar is not showing up.

Comment: Can you see it if you change the background of the scale bar to white?

Comment: Also check the unit and other setting in the scale bar properties, it may be to small or to big to properly display

Comment: a screenshot or such not just of the map but of the properties would be helpful ^^ Like J.R already said, I assume there's an issue in the properties, but none of us can actually help you find it like this.

Comment: I've changed the background with not luck!  I've used the unit and other settings that are populated before and they worked. So its not that.

Comment: I can't add a screen shot of the properties for some reason.